# how to know the current activity of a workflow instance openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I am new to **Odoo OpenERP**, I am working on V8, currently I am trying to understand the workflow.

I am thinking if there is a way to know what is the current activity of a specific workflow instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I would like to share it with you.

you can check the database table, wkf_workitem, in this table you will find the act_id (activity id) field of the latest executed activity on the workflow instance (inst_id).

Hope this may help.
Feel free to contact me for any detail.